# nonlinear sequence to sequence transformations

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, summation, cesaro-summable

i know matrix methods such as Cesaro,Holder,Riesz are regular linear sequence transformations.

i wonder if there is any regular nonlinear sequence transformation?